# Http Batch Response does not complete in Web API 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api2, datajs

HttpBatchResponseMessage responses never fully return on my machine, it only returns the headers but does not complete the request. I tryed the following OData sample, it works just fine on my colleagues machine:

http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v3/ODataEFBatchSample/ReadMe.txt

*(super simple to try, download, start, show network requests in the browser or fiddler)*

I would really appreciate ideas for further investigations!

## The response

from POST to http://localhost:15625/odata/$batch only returns the headers without any content

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:2114
Content-Type:multipart/mixed; boundary=batchresponse_1c6b4001-17b8-41bb-9579-970cdc358dba
DataServiceVersion:3.0
Date:Tue, 10 Mar 2015 17:03:40 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
X-SourceFiles:=?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNca2phcnRhblxEb3dubG9hZHNcT0RhdGFFRkJhdGNoU2FtcGxlXE9EYXRhRUZCYXRjaFNhbXBsZVxvZGF0YVwkYmF0Y2g=?=
```

## Figured out ...

The returned headers already tell the length of the response (**Content-Length:2114**). I tryed to inject some custom classes an figured out:

- Works on my colleagues computer
- The problem occures when returning a ODataBatchContent, worked as I used a StringContent instead (which doesn't do the job)
- The ODataBatchContent serialized perfectly fine when serializing to a MemoryStream

## I Tryed

- Disabling any Firewall, Antivirus software, Software, etc.
- Updating Visual Studio etc., my configuration is nearly identical to the one of from my colleague
- Debugging ... a lot

## Request

POST to /odata/$batch

Status Code:202 Accepted

Headers:

```
Accept:multipart/mixed
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1201
Content-Type:multipart/mixed;boundary=batch_b58d-91a6-2b46
DataServiceVersion:1.0
Host:localhost:15625
MaxDataServiceVersion:3.0
Origin:http://localhost:15625
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:15625/Index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36
```

Thanks.